# Java - Taking user input to create an unknown number of class objects/arrays/arrayLists

Tags: java, class, object, input, sum

I need to allow the user to input any number of students. They press "C" to end data entry. I was thinking to make a student class (my code does not currently represent that) and 4 objects per student. Each set of 4 objects are the number grades that will be summed up and averaged.

I've already tried using a while loop, making arrayLists, and I've looked into maps. Each set of 4 grades corresponds to a student and must be summed and averaged separately.

```
package arrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestGrades {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<String> studentName = new ArrayList<String>(); 
ArrayList<Double> studentGrade = new ArrayList<Double>();
boolean loop = true;

while (loop) {

    System.out.println(" Please Enter Student Name");
    String student = scanner.nextLine();

        if(student.equals("C"))
        {
          break;    
        }
        else
        {
          studentName.add(student);
        }


    System.out.println("Please enter Student Grade");
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

        Double grade = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
        studentGrade.add(grade);  
    }    

    System.out.println(studentName);
    System.out.print(studentGrade);
    }
}
}
```

Problem here really is that I have all the entered numbers in one arrayList and I don't know if I can automatically create a new arrayList each time they enter a new student. Each arrayList would ideally hold just 4 double values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well please consider that grades are related to student and limited to always 4.
Therefore I suggest to implement a dynamic list of a class student with enclosed array of grades.

Example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestGrades {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<Student> studlist = new ArrayList<Student>(); 

boolean loop = true;
while (loop) {

    System.out.println(" Please Enter Student Name");
    String scanedline = scanner.nextLine();

        if(scanedline.equals("C"))
        {
          break;    
        }
        else
        {
          studlist.add(new Student(scanedline));
        }


    System.out.println("Please enter Student Grade");
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
    System.out.print(""+j+">");
        Double scannedgrade = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
        studlist.get(studlist.size() - 1).grade[j]=scannedgrade;
        }    

    System.out.println(studlist.get(studlist.size() - 1).name);
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        System.out.print(studlist.get(studlist.size() - 1).grade[j] + " ");
    System.out.println("");
    }
}

private static class Student 
{
    String name;
    Double [] grade;

    Student (String s)
    {
        this.name = s;
        grade = new Double[4];
    }

}

}
```